# Android Room - CASCADE in dependent table for DELETE and keep untouchable for INSERT operation?

Tags: foreign-keys, android-sqlite, android-room, dao, cascade

I have two tables - `users` and `conversations`. Many `users` may participate in one `conversation` and  one `user` may be a member of many `conversations`

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class User {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userId")
    private String id;  
    ...
    //Getters and setters  
}  

@Entity(tableName = "conversations")
public class Conversation {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "uuid")
    private String id;  
    ...
    //Getters and setters  
}
```

To track which `user` participate in which `conversation` I use third table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_conversation", indices = {@Index(value = {"userId", "conversationUuid"}, unique = true)},
    primaryKeys = {"userId", "conversationUuid"},
    foreignKeys = {
            @ForeignKey(onDelete = CASCADE, entity = User.class,         parentColumns = "userId", childColumns = "userId"),
            @ForeignKey(onDelete = CASCADE, entity = Conversation.class, parentColumns = "uuid",   childColumns = "conversationUuid")
    })
public class JoinUserConversation {
    @NonNull
    private String userId;

    @NonNull
    private String conversationUuid;
    ...
    //Getters and setters
}
```

`Dao` objects:

```
@Dao
public interface UsersDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(User user);
    ...
}

@Dao
public interface ConversationsDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insert(Conversation conversation);
    ....
}
```

When I `delete` a `user` or `conversation` from their tables I need to delete them from `user_conversation` too and I use `onDelete = CASCADE` for this purpose. But when I **`insert`** a `user` or `conversation` to their tables I **do not need to delete** them from `user_conversation`. But as I understand `insert` with `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` will be performed by means of `delete` if inserting entity already exist in the table and corresponding `user` or `conversation` will be deleted from `user_conversation` table. **How to keep `user_conversation` from changes on `insert`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you could accomplish what you want by checking the id of the row to be inserted exists if so update if not then insert.

- Note I tried using `deferred = true` along with `@Transaction` but there is no conflict due to the CASCADE doing what it is supposed to do.

For example, for Users :-

Add

```
@Query("SELECT count() FROM users WHERE userId = :userId")
int getUserCount(String userId);
```

and

```
@Update()
int updateUser(User user);
```

And then have a method, such as :-

```
private void upsertUser(User u) {
    if (mWTDao.getUserCount(u.getId()) > 0) {
        mWTDao.updateUser(u);
    } else {
        mWTDao.insert(u);
    }
}
```

- mWTDao being where all the Dao's exist (same for the example)

## Example

Consider the following extract (from testing code):-

```
    ......... other code

    upsertUser(new User("userid001","Fred"));
    upsertUser(new User("userid002","Mary"));
    upsertUser(new User("userid003","Jane"));
    upsertUser(new User("userid004","Tom"));

    mWTDao.insert( new Conversation("c001","SUBJECT A"));
    mWTDao.insert( new Conversation("c002","SUBJECT X"));

    mWTDao.insert(new JoinUserConversation("userid001","c001"));
    mWTDao.insert(new JoinUserConversation("userid003","c001"));

    mWTDao.insert(new JoinUserConversation("userid002","c002"));
    mWTDao.insert(new JoinUserConversation("userid004","c002"));

    logAllInfo("PRE");

    upsertUser(new User("userid001","Harry"));
    upsertUser(new User("userid002","Gertrude"));
    logAllInfo("POST");

}

private void upsertUser(User u) {
    if (mWTDao.getUserCount(u.getId()) > 0) {
        mWTDao.updateUser(u);
    } else {
        mWTDao.insert(u);
    }
}


private void logAllInfo(String tag) {

    Log.d("INFO" + tag,"Logging Conversations via Original Mapping Table ");

    for (JoinUserConversation juc: mWTDao.getAllJUC()) {
        Conversation c = mWTDao.getConversation(juc.getConversationUuid());
        User u = mWTDao.getUser(juc.getUserId());
        Log.d("INFO" + tag,"\tFor Conversation " + c.getTitle() + "ID is (" + c.getId() + ") User is " + u.getName() + " ID is (" + u.getId() + ")");
    }

    Log.d("MAPINFO" + tag,"Logging Users ");

    for (User u: mWTDao.getAllUsers()) {
        Log.d("USERINFO" +  tag,"\tID is " + u.getId() + " Name is " + u.getName());
    }

    Log.d("CONVINFO","Logging Conversations");
    for (Conversation c: mWTDao.getAllConversations()) {
        Log.d("CONVINFO" + tag,"\tID is " + c.getId() + " Ttitle is " + c.getTitle());
    }
}
```

- This adds 4 users (using the **upsertUser** method) and 2 conversations and some user_conversations
- It displays the information
- It then tries to add already existing users using the **upsertUser** method
- It again displays the information, showing that the existing users have been updated.

## Result

```
2019-09-18 08:14:19.214  D/INFOPRE: Logging Conversations via Original Mapping Table 
2019-09-18 08:14:19.220  D/INFOPRE:     For Conversation SUBJECT AID is (c001) User is Fred ID is (userid001)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.222  D/INFOPRE:     For Conversation SUBJECT AID is (c001) User is Jane ID is (userid003)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.224  D/INFOPRE:     For Conversation SUBJECT XID is (c002) User is Mary ID is (userid002)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.226  D/INFOPRE:     For Conversation SUBJECT XID is (c002) User is Tom ID is (userid004)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.226  D/MAPINFOPRE: Logging Users 
2019-09-18 08:14:19.227  D/USERINFOPRE:     ID is userid001 Name is Fred
2019-09-18 08:14:19.227  D/USERINFOPRE:     ID is userid002 Name is Mary
2019-09-18 08:14:19.227  D/USERINFOPRE:     ID is userid003 Name is Jane
2019-09-18 08:14:19.227  D/USERINFOPRE:     ID is userid004 Name is Tom
2019-09-18 08:14:19.227  D/CONVINFO: Logging Conversations
2019-09-18 08:14:19.228  D/CONVINFOPRE:     ID is c001 Ttitle is SUBJECT A
2019-09-18 08:14:19.228  D/CONVINFOPRE:     ID is c002 Ttitle is SUBJECT X



2019-09-18 08:14:19.233  D/INFOPOST: Logging Conversations via Original Mapping Table 
2019-09-18 08:14:19.236  D/INFOPOST:    For Conversation SUBJECT AID is (c001) User is Harry ID is (userid001)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.239  D/INFOPOST:    For Conversation SUBJECT AID is (c001) User is Jane ID is (userid003)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.241  D/INFOPOST:    For Conversation SUBJECT XID is (c002) User is Gertrude ID is (userid002)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.243  D/INFOPOST:    For Conversation SUBJECT XID is (c002) User is Tom ID is (userid004)
2019-09-18 08:14:19.243  D/MAPINFOPOST: Logging Users 
2019-09-18 08:14:19.244  D/USERINFOPOST:    ID is userid001 Name is Harry
2019-09-18 08:14:19.244  D/USERINFOPOST:    ID is userid002 Name is Gertrude
2019-09-18 08:14:19.244  D/USERINFOPOST:    ID is userid003 Name is Jane
2019-09-18 08:14:19.244  D/USERINFOPOST:    ID is userid004 Name is Tom
2019-09-18 08:14:19.244  D/CONVINFO: Logging Conversations
2019-09-18 08:14:19.245  D/CONVINFOPOST:    ID is c001 Ttitle is SUBJECT A
2019-09-18 08:14:19.245  D/CONVINFOPOST:    ID is c002 Ttitle is SUBJECT X
```

- As can be seen Foreign Key children remain but the details have been updated and there are no new unintended users.